# R Markdown won't knit even though my code chunks work

Tags: r, r-markdown

For some reason, my code chunks work but when I try to knit the file, I have an "object not found" error. Here's the chunk which causes the error:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
chart2 <- all_applicants %>%
  filter(Race == "Asian" | Race == "Black or African American" | Race == "White" | Race == "Hispanic or Latino") %>%
  ggplot(all_applicants, mapping = aes(preferred_role)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = Race)) +
  labs(x = "Preferred Role", y = "Number of Applicants", title = "Preferred Applicant Role by Gender", caption = "Data: 2021 Recruiting Data, Govern for America") + theme_bw()

print(chart2)
table(all_applicants$Race)
```

And here's the error message:

```
Line 57 Error: Problem with `filter()` input `...1` x object 'Race' not found i Input `...1` is `|...`.
```

The variable "Race" is part of the all_applicants dataset which I created in a previous chunk. Even though the chunk itself works as intended, when I knit I get the above error. Any help?

Comment: When you `knit` the file, all commands are run in a new R process. If a chunk works in R but not when you knit, it is almost always because you've changed a variable in your global working environment not using code in a chunk. Try restarting your R session and running each chunk sequentially to make sure all your variable values are up to date. You can add `print(names(all_applicants))` to that chunk to see what columns are available when that code it run.

Comment: If you are certain you have a column `Race` in your `all_applicants` data in the rmarkdown document, then try changing `filter` to `dplyr::filter`. If that works, then somehow `stats::filter` is masking `dplyr::filter`, which seems unlikely given the code you have here. If it does not work, however, perhaps it's because the frame `all_applicants` you have in your working R environment is different than what is passed to or visible within the rmarkdown engine (which is not the same as your desktop).

Comment: See @MrFlicks comment above. It is the most common cause to your problem. Be careful when you do iteractive operations in the console while writing an rmd file.

Answer (score 1):

That might not be the solution to your problem, but a solution for others like me who had a similar problem as you have:
I added a knit specification to the YAML header to save my knitted file in another directory. After I deleted that part, my Markdown file was able to knit again. So maybe the problem is not in the code that you presented, but in your header.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have eval=F in your chunk that defines Race.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31155087)

Answer (score 0):

As weird as it sounds, I solved the same problem by creating a copy of my .Rmd file and moving it into another folder.

Comment: Why would this solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and got things working by deleting the cache folder related to the markdown file and re-running.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this too. My code would run fine if I ran each chunk in order (after sweeping the environment to check) but it would not knit (I have other scripts that knit fine).  I found that I had accidentally included eval=FALSE instead of echo=FALSE to a key Chunk.

Not sure of the right terminology but it is this bit at the start of the chunk.

{r setup, echo=FALSE} which worked
vs
{r setup, eval=FALSE}
which didn't work

I know another person said this was not the answer, but it was the answer I needed.